# A differentiable function is onto or not in higher dimension

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have a differentiable function $ F : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and it's derivative 'function(linear function)' at each point always has non zero determinent then is the function onto? I know it is one-one and onto in small domain but can we extend it over all to whole domain?

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = e^x$$

has non-zero derivative but is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

No: a counterexample already for $n=1$ is $f(x) = \arctan x$.